# Twitter Bootstrap - Print All Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to loop through each tab on a page in Twitter Bootstrap and print the contents of that tab when a button is clicked.  In other words, if there's 5 tabs, it loops through all of them and sends each page to the printer.  The tabs are created dynamically on page load.

Right now I've got:

```
$("#idBtnPrint").click(function() {
        $("#idUlTab").each(function() {
            if (window.print) {
            $(this).window.print();
            return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

But it's not working for me.  I'm not particularly strong on query (probably evident) - can anyone offer any suggestions?  I don't see any comparable code anywhere to start.

Comment: `window.print();` doesn't work like that. You cannot trigger separate print jobs for a single page. Look into using a separate stylesheet for print, see http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I'm already using a print stylesheet... but the tabs are created dynamically and there's always a different number, there's no way (that I can think of) to do it only with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick little jQuery plugin that will do what you are looking for.  To use it, just do `$('#id').print()` in your loop.  If you wish to print the container that your element is in as well, use `$('#id').print({container: true});`

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.print = function(opts) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var options = $.extend({}, $.print.defaults, opts), 
                print_frame = $('<iframe id="print_content' + $.print.frame_num + '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="print_frame" border="0"></iframe>'), 
                frame_doc, 
                frame_head, 
                frame_body, 
                html_base = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>';
            if(options.preview === true) {
                /* Create print modal and overlay */
                var overlay = $('<div id="print_overlay"></div>'), 
                    print_window = $('<div id="print_window"></div>'), 
                    print_controls = $('<div id="print_controls"><a class="print" title="Print">Print</a><a class="cancel" title="Cancel">Cancel</a></div>'), 
                    css = {
                        zIndex: options.zIndex, 
                        top: '0px'
                    };
                overlay.css({
                    width: document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'px', 
                    height: document.documentElement.clientHeight + 'px', 
                    zIndex: options.zIndex - 1
                }).appendTo('body');
                print_controls.find('a').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if($(this).hasClass('print')) {
                        print_frame[0].contentWindow.focus();
                        print_frame[0].contentWindow.print();
                    }
                    else {
                        $.print.destroy();
                    }
                });
                print_window
                    .append(print_controls)
                    .append(print_frame)
                    .css(css)
                    .appendTo('body');
                $(window).bind('resize.print', function(e) {
                    overlay.css({
                        width: document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'px', 
                        height: document.documentElement.clientHeight + 'px'
                    });
                }).bind('scroll.print', function(e) {
                    overlay.css({
                        top: document.documentElement.scrollTop + 'px', 
                        left: document.documentElement.scrollLeft + 'px'
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                print_frame.appendTo('body');
            }

            frame_doc = $('#print_content' + $.print.frame_num)[0].contentWindow.document;
            frame_doc.open();
            frame_doc.write(html_base);
            frame_doc.close();

            /* Append the correct headers to the iframe */
            frame_head = $('head link[media="print"], head link[media="all"]').clone().each(function() {
                $(this).attr('media', 'all'); //In case a preview is being shown, show everything
            });
            if(options.container === true) {
                frame_body = $(this).clone().show();
            }
            else {
                frame_body = $(this).children().clone();
            }

            /* Append the body to the iframe */
            $(frame_doc)
                .find('head')
                    .append(frame_head)
                    .end()
                .find('body')
                    .append(frame_body)
                    .find('a').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    });
            $.print.frame_num++;
            if(options.preview === false) {
                print_frame.css({width: '0px', height: '0px'});
                print_frame[0].contentWindow.focus();
                print_frame[0].contentWindow.print();
            }
            return this;
        });
    };
    $.print = {
        frame_num: 0, 
        defaults: {
            preview: false, 
            container: false, 
            zIndex: 5000
        }, 
        destroy: function() {
            if($('#print_window').length > 0) {
                $('#print_window').remove();
                $('#print_overlay').remove();
                $(window).unbind('resize.print').unbind('scroll.print');
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The corresponding CSS for this would be (don't forget to change the image paths for the print and cancel icons):

```
#print_overlay {
    background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#print_window {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px -465px; /* Re-center the preview */
    padding: 0px 75px;
    width: 794px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}

#print_content {
    margin: 75px 0px;
    border: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#print_controls {
    position: fixed;
    top: 37px;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -81px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#print_controls a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 50px;
}

#print_controls a:hover {
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#print_controls a.print {
    background: url(print.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#print_controls a.cancel {
    background: url(cancel.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div class="print">
Print
</div>
<div class="print">
Print 2
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.print').print({container: true, preview: false});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Kyle - looks great! I'll report back in a couple of days... I'm sure there's other bootstrap users who will benefit from this as well.

Comment: @johnny_n Please look at the update I posted to the answer.  What I originally posted to you was a watered down version of what I had written, but I figured you might be interested in the full plugin.  It allows you to simply print the element, or you can display a preview of what the printed content will look like.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle -- will do, I appreciate you posting the full version!

Comment: Strangely I'm not seeing any big difference (only slight visual difference) between this and the default printing behavior.  It prints the current tab only... the plugin and css are both being included.  I'm using this to trigger `$("#idBtnPrint").click(function() {
        $("#idUlTab").each(function() {
            $('#idToPrint').print({container: true});
            }
        });
    });`  (the idToPrint is the main div inside each tab.

Comment: @johnny_n Can you post a sample of your HTML?  I will post the example I am using, and it seems to be working fine (multiple print dialogs are opened).

Comment: @johnny_n Also, I updated the plugin code so that you don't have to use the `.each` loop.  It will loop through them for you.  `$('.print').print();`

Comment: Thanks, Kyle -- if it works for you, I'll continue to troubleshoot on my end, most of the page is dynamically created so posting the HTML is an endeavor... I'm sure that's the issue.  I'll start with something simple first.

Comment: @johnny_n After reading your question again, it looks like you are using the id `idUlTab` multiple times.  In HTML, you can only use an ID once (unless it is in another iFrame).  Could that be your problem?  I am not sure what else it could be without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle -- this has been put on hold but I did manage to make some progress.  It's not quite that simple -- javacript is not only dynamically creating those tabs but also dynamically constructing the HTML from templates.  And that HTML isn't appearing in the page source/DOM so I can't "get to it" basically.  I'm going to have to speak to the author of that script to work out how/why it's being done this way... but I'm sure I'll get it working.  :-)

Comment: @johnny_n I hope you are able to get it working.  Sometimes, Dynamic HTML can cause some interesting things.

Comment: Yes, let's call it a "side-effect".  I accepted your answer Kyle, I'll post back once I get this settled (hopefully soon!)

Answer (score 1):

Kyle's answer is a great answer to your specific question - i.e. print each tab individually.

But if I may assume you want to do this because printing the page itself only prints the active tab - then I may have an answer that allows you to print each tab as part of the whole page.

The trick is in the CSS.  Use this:

```
    @media print {
      .nav-tabs { display: none !important; }
      .tab-content > .tab-pane { display: block !important; }
      .tab-content > .fade { opacity: 1; }
    }
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hue8q3d/2/) for a full example.